# Make Custom Post Type in Wordpress Not Searchable

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to create a very specific type of Custom Post Type, one that should not allow users to search other posts created with this type of post, but only allow them to see the ones they are sent a link to access. What I have so far is this:

```
 function pp_register_post_type(){
    $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Viajes', 'post type general name', 'negocios' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Viajes', 'post type singular name', 'negocios' ),
    'menu_name'          => _x( 'Viajes', 'admin menu', 'negocios' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Viajes', 'add new on admin bar', 'negocios' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Viajes', 'negocios' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Viajes', 'negocios' ),

);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'negocios' ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'Viajes' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog'
);

register_post_type('pp_portfolio', $args );
}
   add_action('init', 'pp_register_post_type');
```

I thought setting `'publicly_queryable' => true,` to false would do that but what it does instead is to not register a permalink when the post is created. Then when I try to view the post it just sends me to the home page.

How should I set the `$args` to avoid an archive.php to show a list of post either by date or other queries? When someone tries to search for these post types I actually want to output a 404 page. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type.

```
exclude_from_search => 'true'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know how I missed that.